# Why isn't Chrome enabling Omnibox Search for my site?

Tags: xml, search, google-chrome, get

I wanted to implement Chrome's Omnibox search into my site, and followed the relatively simple [instructions by Google.](http://dev.chromium.org/tab-to-search) I can't reveal the site URL, but this is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<ShortName>Search Mysite</ShortName>
<Description>Search the Content of Mysite.com</Description>
<Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://mysite.com/search.php?q=   
{searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

The Omnibox option does not appear in Chrome. What am I doing wrong? All the URLs are typed correctly.

Comment: Most likely, the problem is in the link to the OpenSearch document, or in HTTP headers. Can you setup a test site that demonstrates the problem at an URL you *can* reveal?

Comment: No, the problem with that is that I can't say the domain name at all, sorry. But which link do you mean? The OpenSearchDescription one?

Comment: Ok, because the link above says that the site moved, I updated it to **http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1**, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check the Ctrl+I developer tools and go to the network tab. Do you see chrome making any attempts to pull your osdd file? It does not seem to even attempt to request the osdd file on my test site.

Does Google Chrome support this feature? Or is it just for chromium OS / chromium browser?

Comment: It doesn't request the file for me either. Yes, I was wondering the same thing, but even Wikipedia has this: **<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="/w/opensearch_desc.php" title="Wikipedia (en)" />**.

Comment: I tried a few experiments and the osdd file does not appear on the network tab either. But the search engine is successfully added and appears in the chrome://chrome/settings > Manage Search Engines section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chrome Bug Report 58801](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58801) is a place where someone had asked a similar question. The comment #3 [Comment 3](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58801#c3) answers that one needs to search before the engine is added.

I set up a test site

- visit it
- Click the OK button to perform a mock search
- type "testSiteName.com" +  on your omni box
- you should see a "testSiteName search"
- I got my osdd file from youtube.

This seems to be working for me.

Afterthought: If you want to test something anew, visit chrome://chrome/settings and manage search engines. Delete the search engine of your site and restart the browser. My chrome was displaying the old search till I restarted the browser.

Comment: Yes, successfully searching at least once adds the Omnibox to my site. Thanks!